# How to setup Webpack's HMR in NestJS project in Nx monorepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, webpack-hmr, nomachine-nx

I am trying to enable Webpack HMR in nestjs app in [Nx](https://nx.dev/) monorepo

The nx workspace with nestjs app can be found in the repo [here](https://github.com/SOHELAHMED7/nx-nest-webpack-hmr). It is created by following official [docs](https://nx.dev/react/getting-started/getting-started)

Nestjs webpack HMR docs is [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload#without-cli)

I successfully enabled Webpack HMR in nestjs app without nx monorepo by following the above docs.

How to setup Webpack's HMR in NestJS project in Nx monorepo?

Feel free to ask more details about the question if required

Answer (score 0):

<strike>webpack@5.74.0</strike>

```
yarn add webpack@5.70.0
```

---

### webpack-hmr.config.js

```
...
{
  entry: { main: ['./node_modules/webpack/hot/poll?100', ...config.entry.main ]  }, //this
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      allowlist: ['./node_modules/webpack/hot/poll?100'] // this
    })
  ],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({ paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/] }),
    new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({name: config.output.filename, autoRestart: false}),
  ],
},
...
```

---

### apps/***project-api***/project.json >> targets.build.webpackConfig

```
"webpackConfig": "apps/project-api/webpack-hmr.config.js"
```

### run

```
npx nx build project-api --watch
```

Comment: A little comment to explain your answer would go a long way to improve the quality of it !